# Finding nearest points on MultiLinestring to specific points

Tags: python, shapely

I have a simple MultiLinestring and example points as follows:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, MultiLineString
my_route = MultiLineString([
    [(24.142982, 54.329322), (24.142753, 54.328542)],
    [(24.142753, 54.328542), (24.142638, 54.327449)],
    [(24.142638, 54.327449), (24.142256, 54.325755)],
    [(24.142256, 54.325755), (24.141682, 54.323280)],
    [(24.141682, 54.323280), (24.141529, 54.322232)],
])

A = Point(24.143747, 54.329344)
B = Point(24.140764, 54.323414)
```

Note that `my_route` doesnt contains both of the points.

Now, I want to find a point `A'` belonging to the `my_route` that will be closest to point `A`, and a point `B'` that belongs to `my_route` and is closest to point `B`. I am trying to do that using `interpolate` method on `my_route` object:

```
nearest_point_A = my_route.interpolate(my_route.project(A))
nearest_point_B = my_route.interpolate(my_route.project(B))
```

If I print out the result, it turns out, that nearest_point_A has been found correctly, but the problem is with point nearest_point_B, because it doesn't belong to `my_route`:

```
print(nearest_point_A.coords[0])
print(nearest_point_B.coords[0])
```

You can even check if results points are on `my_route` using intersects method:

```
print(my_route.intersects(nearest_point_A))
print(my_route.intersects(nearest_point_B))
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong and why I can find only nearest_point_A, but nearest_point_B has been found not correct?

Comment: You want to find the nearest line vertex to point A and B? (not the coordinate on the line which is nearest to point A and B)

Comment: I don't want to find vertex, just the two coordinates on the line which first is nearest to point A and second to B.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nearest_points](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#nearest-points):

> Returns a tuple of the nearest points in the input geometries. The
> points are returned in the same order as the input geometries.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, MultiLineString
from shapely.ops import nearest_points

my_route = MultiLineString([
    [(24.142982, 54.329322), (24.142753, 54.328542)],
    [(24.142753, 54.328542), (24.142638, 54.327449)],
    [(24.142638, 54.327449), (24.142256, 54.325755)],
    [(24.142256, 54.325755), (24.141682, 54.323280)],
    [(24.141682, 54.323280), (24.141529, 54.322232)],
])

A = Point(24.143747, 54.329344)
B = Point(24.140764, 54.323414)

nearest_point_A = nearest_points(my_route, A)[0]
nearest_point_B = nearest_points(my_route, B)[0]

for p in [nearest_point_A, nearest_point_B]:
    print(p.wkt)

#POINT (24.142982 54.329322)
#POINT (24.141681996999232 54.32327997944572)
```

[image]

Comment: Note that #POINT (24.141681996999232 54.32327997944572) isn't on the line. you can chceck that using print(my_route.intersects(nearest_point_B)) - it returns False

Comment: I believe it is a "floating point error". `nearest_point_B.distance(my_route) #4.226324459710306e-16`

Comment: Which means it is on the line